# Are elliptic global function fields totally imaginary?

Tags: elliptic-curves, global-fields

Let $K/\mathbb{F}_{q}(X)$ be a global function field extension of degree $2$, having minimal polynomial $Y^{2}=f(X)$, where $f(X)$ is a degree 3 polynomial in $X$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, such that the corresponding curve which covers $\mathbb{P}^{1}_{\mathbb{F}_{q}}$ is an elliptic curve. In other words, if $C$ is such a curve, defined over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, the covering map is: $[x:y:1]\mapsto [x:1]$. It seems to me that without any exceptions on $q$ the point at infinity $[1:0]$ is a ramification point of such a map, therefore there must be only one place above it in $C$. In other words, the extension is always totally imaginary. This argument seems quite obvious to me, but as I couldn't find any reference to it I am wondering if I am forgetting something or if I am making some mistake?

Comment: What is the definition of "totally complex" for a field of characteristic $p$?

Comment: For a quadratic global function field one can have a notion of totally real and totally imaginary (sorry, not complex, I have edited the question) just considering the splitting of the place at infinity, in analogy of what happens with number fields: in case of complete splitting the extension is called totally real, it is called totally imaginary otherwise.

Comment: When you have $y^2=f(x)$ with $f$ of even degree, then there is a meaningful distinction between whether the place at infinity is split or inert, that is, whether the leading coefficient of $f$ is a square or not (in the given finite field). When the degree of $f$ is odd, the place at infinity ramifies and what you choose to call that is a matter of convention. For genus $>1$, the ramification points of the double cover are intrinsically defined but for genus $1$, they are not.

Comment: I was not aware of these facts, are there specific references that you may indicate to me where I can find the precise statements please?